# Sort a vector of strings using Templates

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

Here is the code for sorting a `vector` of `string`s

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <functional>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <ostream>
    using namespace std;
    //using std::greater;
    int main(){

        vector<string>s;
        s.push_back("cat");
        s.push_back("antelope");
        s.push_back("dog");
        s.push_back("elephant");
        s.push_back("snake");
        sort(s.begin(),s.end(),greater<string>());
        for (auto i=s.begin();i!=s.end();++i){
            std::cout<<*i;
        }
             return 0;
    }
```

and here are the errors

```
1>------ Build started: Project: sort_string, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 8/8/2010 4:40:45 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\sort_string.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  sort_string.cpp
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sort_string\sort_string\sort_string.cpp(18): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(679): could be 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(726): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(764): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(811): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(937): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const signed char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(944): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,signed char)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(951): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const unsigned char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(958): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,unsigned char)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(968): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,_Ty)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>,
1>              _Ty=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(1085): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const std::error_code &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(186): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(192): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(199): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::ios_base &(__cdecl *)(std::ios_base &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(206): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::_Bool)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(226): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(short)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(260): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned short)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(280): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(int)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(305): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned int)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(325): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(long)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(345): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned long)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(366): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(__int64)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(386): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned __int64)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(407): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(float)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(427): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(double)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(447): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(long double)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(467): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(const void *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(487): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits> *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::ostream, std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:02.21
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What is the cause of these errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just missing `#include <string>`.

The errors do not relate to sorting, they relate to not finding a suitable overload of `<<` to output a string. If you use `std::string`, then include the respective header.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `#include<string>`

This is strange behavior in Visual Studio that it doesn't points out compile error when u use string directly without specifying `#include<string>` but an error is thrown when u use string with any other any stl object/function which try to use any of the overloaded operators.